# How to detect inserting or deleting an image

Tags: ios

```
NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
textAttachment.bounds = rect;
textAttachment.image = image;

NSAttributedString *attachmentString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.contentTV.attributedText];
[attributedText replaceCharactersInRange:_lastSelectedRange withAttributedString:attributedString];

self.contentTV.attributedText = attributedText;
```

This is my code, but when I insert an image, the textView don't call the delegate method:`- (BOOL)textView: shouldChangeTextInRange: replacementText:`  and `- (void)textViewDidChange:`

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: How do you insert an image exactly?

Comment: I use NSTextAttachment in an UITextView